# How to uninstall and can we delete any folder from /usr

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, software-uninstall

I'm a new Ubuntu 14.04 user, and installed Eclipse Mars, but it's working very slow so I want to uninstall it.

I also installed java jdk 1.8.0_6 5 (`usr/lib/java/jdk 1.8.0_65`), but it not show in the terminal.

I does not appear in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Well, you could open Software Center and delete eclipse, but what about java ? Please open terminal (that's ctrl+alt+t shortcut) and then type `dpkg --get-selections | awk '/jdk/ || /eclipse/'`

Answer (score 0):

The uninstall will depend on the method you used to install.  If you installed via the Software Center or using Synaptic you can use the GUI remove click to uninstall, or the `apt-get` commandline to uninstall.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove [program installed]
```

Replace `[program installed]` with the package name of the program you installed such as `ecliplse`.